# How to set a default select option in HTML dropdown?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I have a form with below HTML structure:

```
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
```

Form the above code, the dropdown looks like 1 is the default selected option. 
Is there anyway, where we can set a default selected option something that is not available in the option list?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The select element cannot have a default value that's absent from the option list.

However, you can set its default option to `display: none`.  It will still display as the value of the select element, but it won't appear in the drop-down list:

```css
select option:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option selected>Default</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
</select>
```

In the above Snippet, you can no longer choose option "Default" once you've chosen another option.

Note that this works in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Edge for Windows.  It does *not* work in Internet Explorer or on an iPad (at least).  A true cross-platform solution would require JavaScript.

Comment: Hi rick. It works, but, when I click the dropdown, the '6' option should not be present in list. That is my requirement.